# How to produce more than one clue from a record?

Tags: cluedin

I am writing a [CluedIn Crawler](http://documentation.cluedin.net/docs/10-Integration/Crawling.html) and when I get data, I get a record that contains an array of referenced records. The code looks like this:

```cs
       public IEnumerable<object> GetData(CrawlJobData jobData)
        {
            if (!(jobData is MyCrawlJobData myCrawlJobData))
            {
                yield break;
            }

            var client = clientFactory.CreateNew(myCrawlJobData);

            foreach (var myModel in client.GetMyModels())
            {
                yield return myModel;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in the clue producer, I want to create a main clue and a clue per each referenced record. But the problem is that the override for the `MakeClueImpl` returns only one `Clue`:

```cs
protected override Clue MakeClueImpl([NotNull] MyModel input, Guid accountId)
{
    // ...
}
```

What can I do to avoid this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `GetData` is `IEnumerable<object>`, you can yield different model objects just from this method:

```cs
public IEnumerable<object> GetData(CrawlJobData jobData)
{
    if (!(jobData is MyCrawlJobData myCrawlJobData))
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var client = clientFactory.CreateNew(myCrawlJobData);

    foreach (var myModel in client.GetMyModels())
    {
        yield return myModel;
                
        foreach (var relatedRecordModel in myModel.RelatedRecords)
        {
            yield return relatedRecordModel;
        }
    }
}
```

And then have two clue producers like:

```cs
protected override Clue MakeClueImpl([NotNull] MyModel input, Guid accountId)
{
    // TODO:
    return clue;
}
```

and

```cs
protected override Clue MakeClueImpl([NotNull] MyRelatedRecordModel input, Guid accountId)
{
    // TODO:
    return clue;
}
```

Yet another way would be just to produce and yield clues just from the `GetData` method and then create a dummy clue producer that will accept a `Clue`:

```cs
public IEnumerable<object> GetData(CrawlJobData jobData)
{
    if (!(jobData is MyCrawlJobData myCrawlJobData))
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var client = clientFactory.CreateNew(myCrawlJobData);

    foreach (var myModel in client.GetMyModels())
    {
        yield return myModel;
                
        foreach (var relatedRecord in myModel.RelatedRecords)
        {
            // return a Clue per related record
            yield return MakeRelatedRecordClue(relatedRecord);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
protected override Clue MakeClueImpl([NotNull] Clue input, Guid accountId)
{
    return clue;
}
```